# Why Lot has to run from Zoar and go to cave

Tags: genesis

> Now Lot went up out of Zoar and settled in the hills with his two daughters, for he was afraid to stay in Zoar; so he lived in a cave with his two daughters.

[Genesis 19:30 NRSV](https://bible.com/bible/2016/gen.19.30.NRSV)

If God had given him that land, why Lot has to run from that city and go to mountain?
Is there any cultural background that can help me understand this passage in better way?